# Why is there no output when I try to print a char?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* var1 = "Z";
    char text = *var1 + 3;
    if(text > 'Z'){
        text = text - 'Z';
        printf("%c\n", text);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Why is there no output, when I run this? If I print with %d instead of %c it works and it prints "3".

Comment: `char* var1 = "Z";` needs to be `const char* var1 = "Z";`

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Because `text - 'Z'` = 3 is not a printable character.